# Minimum number of swaps to achieve prefix constraint

Tags: optimization, compilers, permutations, program-optimization, word-combinatorics

(An isogram is a word in which no letters repeat.)

I'd like to know if there's a standard name for this problem, and/or any standard algorithms. If not, I'm interested in whether anyone has any ideas about how to solve it efficiently.

**Input.**

- A list $X$ of $n$-many isograms.

**Output.**

- An isogram $y$.
- A list $P$ of $(n-1)$-many permutations.

**Rules.**

- The isogram $X[0]$ must be a prefix of the isogram $y$
- The isogram $X[1]$ must be a prefix of the isogram $P[0](y)$
- The isogram $X[2]$ must be a prefix of the isogram $(P[1] \circ P[0])(y)$
- etc.

Additionally, the number of swaps needed to implement the permutations in $P$ must be minimized. Near-optimal solutions are also useful. So, if an algorithm can produce a good but imperfect solution very quickly, that's interesting to me even if the solution isn't always perfect.

**Motivation.** Imagine you have a C function $f$ that contains a block of code defined like so:

```
p(x,y,z);
q(x,y,k);
r(y,x,k);
s(y,z,k);
```

Assume also that $p$, $q$ and $r$ don't modify their arguments. One way to optimize these calls is to build a stack frame that contains all four values $(x,y,z,k)$, and then repeatedly repurpose the stack frame used by one function to meet the needs of the next function. My question is basically how to solve this problem using swaps.